# Skip adding to array if it exists in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `in_array` function to skip adding the same addresses to an array.

Code:

```
$addresses_list = array();
$stmt_select_address_result = $databaseManager->connect()->prepare("SELECT lat,lng,address FROM api_order where userid=683;");
$stmt_select_address_result->execute();

while ($row = $stmt_select_address_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if (!in_array($row, $addresses_list)) {
        array_push($addresses_list, $row);
    }
}
```

I want to skip adding to the arrays if `$row['address']` is the same as an address of `$addresses_list['address']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a temporary variable to store the value of `address` already stored in the `$addresses_list` array. Whenever, you are storing a `$row` in the `$addresses_list` array, you can store the `address` key value in the temporary variable.

Now, everytime you need to check against the temporary variable, whether the key value already exists or not.

**Note** that even [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) recommends using `[]` operator against [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php). So I have changed your code to use `[]` instead.

> Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array, it's
>   better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of
>   calling a function.

Try below (explanation in comments):

```
$addresses_list = array();
$temp_addresses = array(); // Create a temp array

$stmt_select_address_result = $databaseManager->connect()->prepare("SELECT lat,lng,address FROM api_order where userid=683;");
$stmt_select_address_result->execute();

while ($row = $stmt_select_address_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    // check in temporary variable instead
    if (!in_array($row['address'], $temp_addresses)) {

        // add to temp array to avoid duplicate entry in next loop
        $temp_addresses[] = $row['address'];

        $addresses_list[] = $row;
    }
}
```

---

If you really want **unique** address values only, and there is no other use of the duplicate rows. You can rather solve this problem at the SQL query end itself. You can simply use `GROUP BY` on `address`. This will optimize the data packet being transferred from database server to PHP application. Moreover, additional array operations can be done way with.

```
$addresses_list = array();

// It is a good practice to have query string in a separate variable
$sql = "SELECT lat,lng,address 
        FROM api_order 
        where userid=683 
        GROUP BY address;"

$stmt_select_address_result = $databaseManager->connect()->prepare($sql);

$stmt_select_address_result->execute();

while ($row = $stmt_select_address_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // No need for any checks, as you are getting unique addresses only        
    $addresses_list[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Hello again, Can you help me to show the number of repeats?

Comment: @PardisAk what do you mean ? Can you post a new question for the same.

Comment: I mean: I want to show the number of repetitions of an address. for example, if an address repeats 4 times I show a row of like this: Paris-4